# Android support library v7

Tags: android, sdk, android-support-library

I am making an android app that contains action bar and fragment which are not supported for API level 8!
So I just tried to import support library V7 to fix this problem!

But when I try to do it , it doesn't find support library for V7 , there is support.v4 but not v7.
what should I do to fix it?
Should I download anything for my android SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Android Support Library in Your SDK manager under `Extras`. Then Import `appcompat` from following folder in your sdk.

`Android-SDK\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`

Comment: there is another problem now! I have an action bar in the app , and i wrote the code """ private ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar() """ but it doesn't work! When I added """ android.support.v7.app.actionbar """ it happened! what should i do to solve it?

Comment: @AhmedNawaz what do you mean by saying "Then Import appcompat from following folder in your sdk." ? do you mean copying the whole folder to sdk root directory.

Comment: @AhmedNawaz ... my problem really has been solved another else but i will vote up ;)

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to download the library through the SDK manager.
Support library v7 is a library project, so needs to be added as a new project to your workspace.

Note: You can't just drop the .jar in because it has additional XML resources.

There's some pretty thorough instructions on how to add it [located here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat).