# Unable to add Android Support Library version 7

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I want to use `ActionBar` in my app and the min sdk is set to 7. I have to import android.support.v7.*; . but when I import to my app, after putting support library, I see v4 but not v7. I have downloaded the latest version of Android support library by Android SDK manager.

I have researched this question and I found some question like mine but no useful answer. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179340/android-support-library-v7) wasn't useful or I just didn't understand the answer.

Comment: are you using Android Studio or Eclipse ?

Comment: **1** - Import the SDK project into your workspace. **2** - Refer it into your project.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein 2? how to refer ?

Comment: The v4 support library has been around for longer than the v7 and the v7 library uses the v4 library for certain things. For example the v4 library added Fragment capability but didn't have ActionBar. This means sometimes you'll be importing android.support.v4 objects and sometimes android.support.v7 objects.

Comment: Right click on your project name, scroll down below the target APIs and choose the library project

Comment: if you're just starting Android development I suggest to use AndroidStudio instead. Simpler, faster, less memory leaks, more resources and being improved in leaps.

Comment: @Budius are you sure about all these benefits ?

Comment: yes. I've been developing with Android for almost 4 years now and I used Eclipse for most of that time, 1 year ago I changed to AndroidStudio and life was better. Gradle build system is so much better. For example, to solve your problem on AS is simply add 1 line of code `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'` to your build script

Comment: ok. so i will try it soon, although  i have some concerns! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is different from including the android.support.v4 jar. The android.support.v7 libraries are provided as source code that need to be imported, built and then included in your project. The link here has all the information you need : [Android Support Libraries Setup](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#)

Look under, Adding Support Libraries -> Adding libraries with resources. There is information for both Eclipse/ADT and Android Studio. I have successfully included the support action bar in my development.